# Getting sum of middle table columns in left join

Tags: mysql, sql

Below are the tables and the SQL query. I'm doing left join on 3 tables and trying to get sum of the specific columns in each middle table. but the result is wrong.

products table :

```
id | product-name
-----------------
 1 | batman
 2 | goofy
```

size-color table

```
id | product-id | size | color | total
---------------------------------------
 1 |    1       |  33  | blue  |  32
 2 |    1       |  33  | grey  |  11
 3 |    2       |  44  | blue  |  44
 4 |    2       |  33  | grey  |  11
```

sale table

```
id | size-color-id | sold-qty
-------------------------------
1  |     1         |    11
2  |     1         |     8
3  |     4         |     5     
4  |     4         |     2
```

I want to get *total amount* and *sold qty* of each product. I tried :

```
select p.name, sum(c.total), sum(sold-qty)
from products p
LEFT join size-color c 
on p.id = c.product-id
left JOIN sells s
on c.id = s.size-color-id
GROUP by p.id
```

but I got wrong results in total because we have duplicated rows in size-color table.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complicated.  You need to aggregate the `sales` table at the "size color" level.  Then join to `size_color` and aggregate again:

```
select p.name, sc.total, sc.qty
from products p left join
     (select sc.product_id, sum(sc.total) as total,
             sum(s.qty) as qty
      from size_color sc left join
           (select s.size_color_id, sum(sells) as sells
            from sells s
            group by s.size_color_id
           ) s
           on s.size_color_id = sc.id
      group by sc.product_id
     ) sc
     on sc.product_id = p.id;
```

In your version of the query, the total in `size_color` is being multiplied by the number of sales for that `id`.